# Dimension too large error while using path decoration in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, bugs

An error occurs when connecting the path decorations.

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.12 ...lot[] ({-sin(\t r)}, {cos(\t r) + 5e-2*\t});
                                              
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

Here's my MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [domain=0:2.1*pi,variable=\t,smooth,samples=55, 
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow{latex}}}, 
            postaction={decorate}
            ]%
            plot[] ({-sin(\t r)}, {cos(\t r) + 5e-2*\t});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you comment out a part of the code with `postaction=decorate`, compilation succeeds. Is it a bug or am I missing something? The problem is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `smooth` option, the point are connected by bezier curves. Bezier curves have control points. Maybe one of these points is falling too far and `tikz` complains.

A workaround is to disable the `smooth` option and add more samples.

MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [domain=0:2.1*pi,variable=\t,samples=105, 
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow{latex}}}, 
        postaction={decorate}
        ]%
        plot[] ({-sin(\t r)}, {cos(\t r) + 5e-2*\t});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yields: [image: Result without smooth option]

Comment: See also: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/748